# 'getErrorMsg' is deprecated in Joomla 4 and what would be the equivalent

Tags: custom-component, joomla-4.x

In my custom Joomla component, I got the below code

```
$db = Joomla\CMS\Factory::getDbo();
//some code
if (!$row->bind($this->_formdata)) {
  if($db->getErrorMsg()){
    //do some code
  }
  return false;
}
//some code
```

I understand that the method `getErrorMsg` is deprecated in Joomla 4.  What is the best way to get the DB error inside the model `store` method.

Answer (score 5):

I try to give just a short answer on this. We cannot say that there is an “equivalent” of your code snippet in **Joomla 4** since Joomla has been handling errors with using core PHP Exceptions. And your code sample would get error in newer Joomla 3 also.

The old **JError** class were deprecated quite long time ago (**at Joomla 3.1**). The code editors shows this obviously at older error handlings in codes inside Joomla (at `getError()`, `setError()`, `getErrorMsg()` and so on…)

The `bind()` method - if it is the Table class method - is throwing an Exception `\InvalidArgumentException`, if the data (first parameter of the method: $src) is not an object or an array. Or if that method would be the Joomla Form class `bind()` method then it thrown an `\UnexpectedValueException`.

The important part to understand at this question is that we have to `catch` the `\Exception` thrown in the method (otherwise it will cause a PHP Fatal error of Uncaught exception…), so we have to use a `try-catch` block in this code and catch the Exception given in the **method** `bind()` which we are using in this part of the code.

```
try 
{
    $row->bind($this->_formdata);
} 
catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e)
{
    // $e->getMessage(); // Exception message already set in the method we try to use...
    // do some code using the $e->getMessage(), but do not return it...
    // Factory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($e->getMessage(), 'error'); // for example
    // or log it: Log::add($e->getMessage(), Log::WARNING, 'jerror');
    // or you can ignore the Exception
    return false;
}
```